# Flip page using ng-animations

Tags: html, css, angularjs, ng-animate

Using routing i go from one page to another. While doing this I want to have an animation effect of flip.

Something like this http://davidwalsh.name/demo/css-flip.php

Note: I am going from one page to another, I dont want to have two modules on same page and apply flip.

Has anyone got the best way to do it?

Comment: take a look this project: http://augus.github.io/ngAnimate/

Comment: Wonderful job Deividi, Will explore your code and will look if it helps in thins usecase.

Comment: another good resource is the http://www.yearofmoo.com/ blog. This guy works in angular team also.